# How to resolve Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'outerHTML' of null?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

The error is not disabling the page from rendering correct results; however, it is quite annoying! I am showing the HTML and JavaScript portion of the code where the error is originating from. Please assist me with this as I have been attempting to resolve the issue for hours now without any effect!

Code:

```js
google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Element', 'Density', { role: 'style' }],
  ['Copper', 8.94, '#b87333', ],
  ['Silver', 10.49, 'silver'],
  ['Gold', 19.30, 'gold'],
  ['Platinum', 21.45, 'color: #e5e4e2' ]
 ]);

 var options = {
  title: "Density of Precious Metals, in g/cm^3",
  bar: {groupWidth: '95%'},
  legend: 'none',
 };

 var chart_div = document.getElementById('chart_div');
 var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(chart_div);

 google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
  chart_div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">';
  console.log(chart_div.innerHTML);
 });

 chart.draw(data, options);
 document.getElementById('png').outerHTML = '<a href="' + chart.getImageURI() + '" target="_blank"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span></a>';

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Chart 1 -->
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="drawChart()" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Chart</button>

<!-- Modal 1 -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer" style="text-align: center;">
    <div id='png'></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: (Note: you don't need the `!!` in `if (!!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident\/7\./))`)

Comment: Welcome to SO, your question does not fit the site rules. Please read "how to ask" http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and "create a minimal complete verifiable example" http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thank you! This does not resolve my error but I appreciate any assistance with shortening my code!!

Comment: So `document.getElementById('png2')` returns null?! At time you call this code, the element with ID png2 isn't in the DOM (or in same document context than running snippet)

Comment: isolate your error, and post the details of the error (like line number, type of error, actions to produce it...) along with the minimal code that reproduces the error, or better yet, upload it to a jsfiddle or similar site.

Comment: I am honestly not quite sure how to upload it as it's pulling from another HTML via Django. As A. Wolff states it appears to be an issue with document.getElementById('png2').outerHTML = '<a href="' + chart2.getImageURI() + '" target="_blank"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span></a>';.

Comment: Edited my post with a chart that will function and show error.

Comment: @gcampbell probably even better is `if (/Trident\/7\./.test(navigator.userAgent))`

Comment: Does that matter as the error is not present in IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

Replace `outerHTML` with `innerHTML`

#### (sort of) an explanation

You have this line inside a function that's executed multiple times. After the first time, the `#png` element no longer exists, so subsequent calls (like clicking the chart button) cause it to error. Placing the content *inside* the element will ensure that it's always there on subsequent calls.

```js
google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Element', 'Density', { role: 'style' }],
  ['Copper', 8.94, '#b87333', ],
  ['Silver', 10.49, 'silver'],
  ['Gold', 19.30, 'gold'],
  ['Platinum', 21.45, 'color: #e5e4e2' ]
 ]);

 var options = {
  title: "Density of Precious Metals, in g/cm^3",
  bar: {groupWidth: '95%'},
  legend: 'none',
 };

 var chart_div = document.getElementById('chart_div');
 var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(chart_div);

 google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
  chart_div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">';
  console.log(chart_div.innerHTML);
 });

 chart.draw(data, options);
 document.getElementById('png').innerHTML = '<a href="' + chart.getImageURI() + '" target="_blank"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span></a>';

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Chart 1 -->
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="drawChart()" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Chart</button>

<!-- Modal 1 -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer" style="text-align: center;">
    <div id='png'></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Fantastic! That works perfectly. Thank you so much for the assistance!!